# g++ error: "references internal linkage entity" when compiling a module interface

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20

I'm teaching myself C++ through *Professional C++, 5th Edition*, and I encountered this problem in Chapter 1. Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
// class.cxx
export module mod;

const int default_val { 0 };

export class Example
{
  // This line causes the problem.
  int value { default_val };
};
```

Compile it:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts class.cxx
class.cxx:5:14: error: ‘class Example’ references internal linkage entity ‘const int default_val’
    5 | export class Example
      |              ^~~~~~~
class.cxx:1:8: error: failed to write compiled module: Bad file data
    1 | export module mod;
      |        ^~~~~~
class.cxx:1:8: note: compiled module file is ‘gcm.cache/mod.gcm’
```

I've tried to search this error, but didn't find it on the internet.

If we don't use `default_val` in the class:

```cpp
export module mod;

const int default_val { 0 };

export class Example
{
  int value { 0 };
};
```

or if the file is not a module interface:

```cpp
const int default_val { 0 };

class Example
{
  int value { default_val };
};
```

Then it compiles.

So, what causes the error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

---

OS: Arch Linux on Kernel 6.5.9

Gcc version: 13.2.1 20230801

Comment: Side note: You have to be a little careful with modules. At this point g++'s module support is incomplete and there are probably a more than a few bugs still lurking and waiting for the community to trip over.

Comment: This compiles just fine with Clang, so probably a GCC bug. If you want to play with modules, you'll probably have a better time with either MSVC or Clang.

Comment: Try `inline const int default_val { 0 };`.

Comment: Also, it might be too early to use modules in practice. Maybe the book is trying to be future-proof, but I'd wait another year or two, and use the traditional compilation model for now.

Comment: @LHLaurini Thanks. I can comfirm Clang compiles it well. I've reported it as a bug at <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=112621>

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. Adding `inline` makes it work. Thanks for your suggestion also.